# Do I need to make a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm at the early stages of developing my app and I'd like to start testing it on others' devices. Can I not just connect their phones to my computer and use XCode to install the app on their devices the same way I installed it onto mine? Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: As of Xcode 7 and iOS 9, I don't think you need a provisioning profile as long as the device is hooked up to your computer. If you want to try to build an archive, though, you will need a provisioning profile.

Comment: People can continue to use the app even after their phone is disconnected from my computer, right? That seems to be the case with my own device.

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of xcode you do not need to.

Answer (score 0):

In the lates version of XCode you don't need to create a provisional profile but you will need to add your apple dev account.

If you have any issue you could try to create a generic dev provisional profile the one that use a '*' indicator